# QGIS Server: list metadata of all available services and layers

Tags: qgis, metadata, qgis-server

I would like to autogenerate a landing page for a QGIS Server where all available services and layers with the corresponding metadata is available.

It is meant as documentation for within an organisation. I am not looking for a webclient. I am looking for something similar Esri provides for ArcGIS servers.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is a new API that might be useful for your case, see https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/38189 for a start.